# how i can set query id from mysql's table with global var?

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm new in MySQL and i've a question . In my new application, I used Nodejs and MySQL module to connect my database . 
So i need to query with a sepecific var and get similar cloumn's tables .
Here's my code:

```
var sm = "salam";

con.query('SELECT * FROM `news` WHERE title = "'+sm+'"',
function(err, rows, fields) {
    if(err) throw err;
    //postChecker = data.children().nextAll('h3').text().replace(/  /g,'');
    //console.log(fields);
    console.log(rows);

});
```

But in console, Nothings to retrun :

```
[nodemon] starting `node server.js`
app runnig on port 8008
Connection established .
[]
```

In the event that i've a similar table in my database .

Comment: if you get no rows, then no records were matched. did you check if you actually have `salam` records in there?

Comment: When i used `SELECT * FROM news WHERE title = "salam" `, console return some tables thats have a title cloumns similar `salam`

Answer (score 0):

The answer is :

```
con.query('SELECT * FROM `cinemapress` WHERE `title` = ?', [sm],
function(err, rows, fields)
```